# Alternate table row color change

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created a form as follows and I want to change the row color alternatively. I have added jquery script in head but its not working. I don't know what wrong. Please somebody solve this.

Thanks in advance.

**Home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.dataTables.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
{
        $('#example').dataTable();
    } );
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("table.dataTable tbody tr :even").addClass("d0");
   $("table.dataTable tbody tr :odd").addClass("d1");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="example" class="row-border" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
<th>Client</th>
                <th>Financial Year</th>
                <th>Short Description</th>
                <th>Full Description</th>
                <th>File Upload</th>
                <th>Assign TO</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        **<tr class="d0">**
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>2014-15</td>
            <td>Hi</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Information.pdf</td>
            <td>P232</td>
            <td>Edit</td>
        </tr>
        **<tr class="d1">**
            <td>C2</td>
            <td>2015-16</td>
            <td>Hi</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Tech.xls</td>
            <td>P17</td>
            <td>Edit</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Style.css**

```
table.dataTable tbody tr {
  background-color: #FFC;
}
```

Comment: use pseudo selectors odd and even

Answer (score 0):

you can use this style

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
  color: white;
  background: black;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that only with CSS:

```
#example tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #FFC }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use like this. Why need to use jquery??

```
 table.dataTable tbody tr { background-color: #FFC }
 table.dataTable tbody tr:nth-child(2n) { background-color:grey }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qLvkpq99/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use two different class in css file :

```
table.dataTable tbody tr.d0 {
  background-color: #FFC;
}
table.dataTable tbody tr.d1 {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```